# Java Applet起動時にclassnotfoundexception

Tags: java, jsf

XHTMLからJava Appletを起動しようとしましたがhoge.classが存在しないとclassnotfoundexceptionが発生します。LocalのEclipse環境では起動しましたが、Glassfishにデプロイするとエラーが発生します。

以下は起動するときに呼び出すindex.xhtmlです。
class,jar,xhmtl共にWebContentフォルダに入れてあります。

```
<div style="margin: 0 auto;">
<object type="application/x-java-applet" codebase="." width="200px" height="50px">
<param name="code" value= "hoge.class" />
<param name="codebase" value="." />
<param name="archive" value="signedHoge.jar" />
<param name="archive" value="hoge.jar" />
</object>
```

よろしくお願い致します。

※編集
・フォルダ構成
WebContent
- index.xhtml
- hoge.class ※1
- signedhoge.jar
- hoge.jar

※1
hoge.classは同プロジェクトの以下に作成したものを移動しました。
build
- test
-- hoge.class

・jarファイルは以下のコマンドで作成しました。

```
keytool -genkey -keyalg rsa -storepass changeit -alias appletkey -keypass changeit -validity 365

jar cfM hoge.jar hoge.class

jarsigner -storepass changeit -keypass changeit -signedjar signedHoge.jar hoge.jar appletkey
```

・マニフェストファイル内容

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Created-By: 1.8.0_45 (Oracle Corporation)
Permissions: sandbox
Name: hoge.class
SHA-256-Digest: RZ71edQJoTbT9OHsDBLcXXJ+fMthkHIynfD/+mzXfRk=
```

Answer (score 1):

- archive
  hoge.classを含む署名済みのjarのみを指定します。
  `<param name="archive" value="signedHoge.jar" />`
- マニフェスト
  7u51以降ではMANIFEST.MFファイルにPermissions属性が必須です。
  [【Java 7 u51 関連情報(1)】Java 7 Update51におけるRIAの新しいセキュリティ要件について](https://blogs.oracle.com/otnjp/entry/java_7_u51_update_info)
- 署名
  7u51以降、自己署名はブロックされるので証明書の購入か例外サイトへの追加が必要です。
  [Generating a Certificate Signing Request (CSR) for a Public Key Certificate](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/security/sigcert/index.html#GenCSR)
  [どうすれば例外サイト・リストを構成できますか。](https://www.java.com/ja/download/faq/exception_sitelist.xml)

Comment: 回答有難うございます。xhtmlを指摘通り修正しましたが、問題は解決しません。

Comment: *.classファイルをWebContentにおいても読まれませんが、必要なものはすべてjarに入っていますか？アプレットのJavaコンソールやサーバーログからsignedHoge.jarやhoge.jarで404などになっていないかわかりますか？

Comment: jar,class共にWebContentに配置しています。必要な物は全てjar化していますし、ログ等を見ましたがエラーは履いてませんでした。
質問に詳しい詳細を追記しました。よろしくお願い致します。

Comment: 上記すべてを実行しましたが、いまだに例外が発生します。
Javaのバージョンなども調査しましたが問題はないと思いました。
マニフェストファイルの内容を質問に追加します。
よろしくお願い致します。